# Return the smallest unique value in a given array - C Language

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I'm not sure what sort of algorithm to apply here. My thoughts are that I should go about finding all the unique values first and then from there I should grab the minimum. However, I'm not sure how to implement this. I'm trying to do this in C.

The only constraints are that I can only use `#include <stdio.h>` `#include <string.h>`.

Comment: The question is not clear to me. What should happen if the smallest value in the array is not unique, i.e. what if it exists several times in the array? Do you want to discard that value then and find the next lowest value?

Comment: In the array 2,3,2,4,5, should the function return 2 (even though it is not unique) or 3 (because it is the lowest unique value) or -1 (because the lowest value is not unique)?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: 2 is not the smallest unique value, so clearly it should not be returned.

Comment: The thing I'm struggling with is how to write this code down as i've just gotten into coding and so I'm a noob.

Comment: @DevinKent: Is this for a class? What class? Is performance important? Context could help discern what algorithm is intended and possibly what tools to use. An obvious way is to sort the array, then go through the elements from the start, stopping with the first one that is unique.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: It seems clear to me. There is an array A. Let V be the set of values that are in A no more than once each (V = { x | ∃ i: A[i] = x and ∄ j: j ≠ i and A[j] = x}). Return the smallest element of V or an indication that V is empty.

Comment: @EricPostpischil This is a task which I retrieved from online. The only constraints are that I can only use #include <stdio.h> #include <string.h>. Performance and such isn't important.  Your algorithm of sorting the values from smallest to biggest and then stopping at the first unique one sounds perfect. Problem is i'm not sure how to implement it. Also, in regards to the inputs, i'll have an array comprised of integers and from there the length can be deduced.

Comment: Give it more than 4 minutes and I'm sure you can work the problem a little in your head! It'll be much more fulfilling (and useful) than someone just handing you the solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if sorting is necessary. You can just go through the whole array from start to end (in a loop) and always remember (in a variable) the lowest unique value you have encountered so far. Whenever you encounter a lower value, you compare this value with all other elements of the array in order to determine whether it is unique. If it indeed is unique, you remember this new value instead of the previous one and continue with the rest of the array. At the end of the loop, you simply return the value of the variable which contains the lowest unique value you encountered.

Comment: However, if you sort the array first (for example using the [qsort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) function), then it will be easier for you to program, as all you have to do then is to return the first unique value in the sorted array. But qsort is in stdlib.h and you said you are only allowed to use stdio.h and string.h. Therefore, I am afraid you are not allowed to use qsort (or any other predefined sorting function). Therefore, it may be easier for you to not use a sorting function at all, because you would have to program it yourself.

Comment: @DevinKent: Yes, that should also be possible. You can first find the unique values and then find the minimum value. My proposed algorithm combines both steps in one, but since you said performance was not an issue, you can do both steps seperately. However, you will have to allocate memory for an additional array then, to store the unique values.

Comment: Are you asking about how to implement a particular algorithm in C, or are you asking about the algorithm to use?

Comment: Modify the question to change it substantially breaks the existing answers and is inappropriate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question was modified substantially, breaking the existing answers.

Comment: I have submitted an edit proposal to restore the original question (in edited form). The OP overwrote the original question with a follow-up question, instead of posting it as a comment or as a new question. After that, OP has been inactive for several months and did not fix it. Only the original question received answers, so I believe it should be restored.

Comment: Meanwhile, [my edit proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25621067) has been rejected, for reasons that don't make sense to me. All I did in my edit proposal was rollback and combine the revisions 8 and 1. Revision 1 contained the original question (which was closed) whereas revision 8 caused the question to be reopened, but overwrote important details of the original question. Therefore, I believe it was appropriate for me to merge both revisions into one. Maybe @EricPostpischil would like to apply my edit proposal, because he has sufficient reputation points?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: On the other hand, I am considering reformulating the question, so that it could possibly be more useful to other people.

Comment: @DevinKent: I see that my previous statement that you have been inactive for several months is no longer correct. It now says that you were seen a few days ago. Therefore, I would like to request that you clarify whether the current question that you have changed the question to is intended as a new question or whether you were attempting to restore the original question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Now that  have reached 2000 reputation points, I was able to edit the question myself. I have now rolled back the question to revision 4, which is the revision that you edited last. However, I am not sure if this was appropriate, as this revision of the question was closed for "needs detail or clarity" and reopened in revision 8. But revision 8 seems worse than revision 4, as important parts of the original question had been removed in revision 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the algorithm you propose in your question (i.e. to first find all unique values and then find the lowest one), a possible implementation looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// NOTE: The second parameter array_size specifies the number of
// int elements in the array, NOT the size of the array in bytes.
int find_unique_min( int *array_start, int array_size )
{
    int *unique_values; //pointer to the dynamically allocated array with the unique values
    int num_unique_values; //number of values in the secondary array
    int minimum; //smallest unique value found so far
    int i, j; //loop counter variables

    // We don't know yet how many unique values there will be, so we don't know
    // how big the secondary array which holds the unique values must be.
    // However, in the worst case, every value is unique, which means that in
    // the worst case, the secondary array must have the same size as the 
    // primary array. Therefore, we make it the same size.
    unique_values = malloc( array_size * sizeof( int ) );
    if ( unique_values == NULL ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Memory allocation error\n" );
        return -1;
    }

    // This variable specifies the number of valid elements in the
    // secondary array, which must be set to zero for now.
    num_unique_values = 0;

    //fill secondary array with unique values
    for ( i = 0; i < array_size; i++ )
    {
        // compare the current array element with all other elements
        for ( j = 0; j < array_size; j++ )
        {
            // Since the comparison will say the values are identical when
            // comparing an element with itself, we must also check whether we
            // are comparing the element with itself.
            if ( array_start[i] == array_start[j] && i != j ) goto not_unique;
        }

        // We have now determined that the current array element is unique,
        // so we add it to the secondary array.
        unique_values[num_unique_values++] = array_start[i];

not_unique:
        continue;
    }

    //return -1 if no unique values were found
    if ( num_unique_values == 0 )
    {
        free( unique_values );
        return -1;
    }

    //find lowest value in secondary array and return it
    minimum = INT_MAX;
    for ( i = 0; i < num_unique_values; i++ )
    {
        if ( unique_values[i] < minimum ) minimum = unique_values[i];
    }

    free( unique_values );

    return minimum;
}
```

The only reason I included `<stdlib.h>` (which seems to be forbidden by the rules of your assignment) was because I needed to dynamically allocate memory for the secondary array to store the unique values. If you allocate a static array instead, you can get rid of that include directive. However, for a static array, the maximum number of unique numbers must be known at compile time (in order to determine how much memory to allocate).

Alternatively, you can combine both steps (finding the unique values and finding the minimum value) into one. That way, you don't need a secondary array and you also don't need to (dynamically) allocate memory for it. In that case, you also don't have to `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Combining both steps could be done using the following algorithm:

You can just go through the whole array from start to end (in a loop) and always remember (in a variable) the lowest unique value you have encountered so far. Whenever you encounter a lower value, you compare this value with all other elements of the array in order to determine whether it is unique. If it indeed is unique, you remember this new value instead of the previous one and continue with the rest of the array. At the end of the loop, you simply return the value of the variable which contains the lowest unique value you encountered.

An implementation of this algorithm could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef INT_MAX
#define INT_MAX 2147483647
#endif

// NOTE: The second parameter array_size specifies the number of
// int elements in the array, NOT the size of the array in bytes.
int find_unique_min( int *array_start, int array_size )
{
    int minimum; //smallest unique value found so far
    int i, j; //loop counter variables

    minimum = INT_MAX;

    for ( i = 0; i < array_size; i++ )
    {
        if ( array_start[i] < minimum )
        {
            // test if current element value is unique
            for ( j = 0; j < array_size; j++ )
            {
                if ( array_start[i] == array_start[j] && i != j ) goto not_unique;
            }

            minimum = array_start[i];
        }
not_unique:
        continue;
    }

    //if no unique value was found, return -1
    if ( minimum == INT_MAX ) return -1;

    return minimum;
}
```

Please note that normally, `INT_MAX` should not be defined manually. The only reason I did this is because of the restriction mentioned in the question which prevented `#include <stdlib.h>` from being used.

Comment: If you use stdlib.h, might as well just sort the data

Comment: I only use stdlib.h for dynamic memory allocation, because the required amount of memory for the secondary array is not known at compile-time. It is possible to get around this problem, for example by allocating a static array instead of using dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @DevinKent: I have now added the code for my algorithm which combines both steps and does not use `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: Hmmm, I just noticed that stdlib.h is also required for the constant INT_MAX. However, that can simply be replaced with the number 2147483648.

Comment: @DevinKent: Then my program must have a bug. I will now test that array on my computer and debug it.

Comment: @DevinKent: I was unable to reproduce the bug you mentioned, However, I have changed my code a bit (and updated my answer accordingly), because my code didn't compile due to INT_MAX not being defined after removing `#include <stdlib.h>`. I am now defining it myself, if it is not already defined. Could it be that the bug you mentioned is occuring because you didn't call the function properly? If you increase the size of the array to 10 elements, the second parameter must also be set to 10.

Comment: @DevinKent: Meanwhile, I have also fixed the indentation in my last code example in two places. The line `if ( array_start[i] == array_start[j] && i != j ) goto not_unique;` was not indented enough and the line with the label `not_unique:` was indented too much.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Just wanted to give you a special thanks, as someone new to the programming game you've been extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet does what you want. First, it separates the unique values of the array `arr` into another array `unique_values`. Then, it finds the smallest value of that last array, giving you the smallest and unique value overall. Note that this is a crude implementation, it would be best to order them first in ascending order and then iterate it until finding the first different value. However, since you say that performance is not an issue, this a crude but small and clean code snippet for you to grasp.

```
int main ()
{
    const int len = 10;
    int arr[len]; //Fill it before continuing and change len accordingly
    int unique_values[len];
    int actual_len = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
        {
            if (i != j && arr[i] == arr[j])
            {
                goto _next;
            }
        }
        unique_values[actual_len] = arr[i];
        actual_len++;
        _next:
        continue;
    }
    int unique_smallest = unique_values[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < actual_len; i++)
    {
        if (unique_values[i] < unique_smallest)
        {
            unique_smallest = unique_values[i];
        }
    }
}
```