# Is the 'goto' statement safe?

Tags: c++

I'm writing this code but I wonder if the goto statement is safe, I mean, is it efficient or I can do better?
here's the code, it works good, but I just want to know if it's safe (infinite loop etc..)

```
int main()
{
    list <Song> s{ {"Mi Gente","JBalvin"}, {"In Da Club","50 Cent"}, {"Player Hater","Kollegah"} };
    Song s1;
    string name;
    auto it = s.begin();
    //list<Song>::iterator it1;

    current_playlist(s);
    main_menu();
loop:   
    Enter_sel();

    if (c == 'F' || c == 'f')
    {
        cout << *it << endl;
        goto loop;
    }
    else if (c == 'N' || c == 'n')
    {
        it++;
        cout << *it << endl;
        goto loop;
    }
    else if (c == 'P' || c == 'p')
    {
        it--;
        cout << *it << endl;
        goto loop;
    }

    else if (c == 'Q' || c == 'q')
        system("exit");


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code itself has issues. Ex: what happens when the first thing someone types is `P` ? You move your iterator one step *before* `s.begin()`, then dereference it. Not good. Likewise perusing to the end, then hitting `N`.

Comment: ```
else if (c == 'P' || c == 'p')
 {
  if (it == s.begin())
  {
   cout << "You cannot play, please try again" << endl;
   Enter_sel();
  }
  else
  {
   it--;
   cout << *it << endl;
   goto loop;
  }
 }
```

Comment: I'd also lose the `system("exit")`. And as far as that goes, use an infinite `while(true)` loop, lose all the goto's, and `break` on (apparently?) anything besides the first three cases. The `Q` case seems pointless, but the workflow is questionable, since anything besides the forward, next, and print cases will either (a) run `system("exit")`, or (b) conclude `main`. In a word, that combination is... odd.

Comment: can you write me your version of code to see?

Comment: Go back one rev in Thomas' answer. it's pretty close to what I was referring.

Comment: You can use `goto` if you want. However, it makes your program harder for you and other people to read and understand. Therefore, you should normally use `for`, `while` or `do`...`while` loops instead, if possible. In your example, they are just as efficient as `goto`. There are only very few cases where using `goto` instead may be meaningful.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel can you give some examples where goto is efficient please?

Comment: @Idriss: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58460043/12149471) is the only one case I can think of where it was appropriate for me to use `goto`. In that case, I did not use `goto` to implement the actual loop; I used `for` to implement both the outer and the inner loop. However, I did need to use `goto` to exit the inner loop and to jump to a certain place in the outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid it. It can cause problems and makes your code difficult to understand. Use a loop

```
int main()
{
    list<Song> s{ { "Mi Gente", "JBalvin" }, { "In Da Club", "50 Cent" }, { "Player Hater", "Kollegah" } };
    Song s1;
    string name;
    auto it = s.begin();
    //list<Song>::iterator it1;

    current_playlist(s);
    main_menu();

    while (true) {
        Enter_sel();

        if (c == 'F' || c == 'f') {
            cout << *it << endl;
        }
        else if (c == 'N' || c == 'n') {
            it++;
            cout << *it << endl;
        }
        else if (c == 'P' || c == 'p') {
            it--;
            cout << *it << endl;
        }

        else if (c == 'Q' || c == 'q')
            system("exit");
        else
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Notice that OP doesn't loop for non-handled characters, contrary to your version.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, you are right. I didn't see it and I fixed it.

Comment: what do you mean @Jarod42

Comment: @Idriss: There was an error before edit for example for `'A'` with end of program for you, loop with old answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will encounter difficulties if you use goto this way. In fact the presence of goto means the program is not correctly structured. To be able to use goto in programs you first must learn how to avoid it.

```cpp
Enter_sel();
while (c == 'F' || c == 'f' ||
       c == 'N' || c == 'n' ||
       c == 'P' || c == 'p')
{
    switch(c)
    {
    case 'N': case'n':
        it++;
        break;
    case 'P': case'p':
        it--;
        break;
    }

    cout << *it << endl;
    Enter_sel();
}
if (c == 'Q' || c == 'q')
    system("exit");
```

Comment: thanks, I was going to work with switch case but I wanted to change a little bit because I master switch case